# Arduino Uno - temperature sensor DS18B20 not responding

Tags: temperature-sensor, ds18b20

I try to use a new DS18B20+ temperature sensor (sealed water proof version).

It doesn't work. My own code doesn't work, examples from DallasTemperature Library don't work, example from OneWire library doesn't work.

For example function `sensors.getDeviceCount();` (DallasTemperature library) returns '0'.
Function `tempSensor.getTempCByIndex(0);` returns 65409 (int variable). `!ds.search(addr)` (OneWire library) also always return '0'. Then I am sure, Arduino code is alright.

I am sure DS18B20 is connected correctly:

- white wire (onewire data) - onewire Arduino pin (tested with pin 2 and pin 13)
- red wire (+V) - 5V Arduino pin
- black wire (GND) - GND Arduinp pin
- between 5V and DATA there is a 4k7 resistor

I have measured resistances between the temperature sensor's wires:

- '+V' to 'data': 4,7 kOhm
- 'GND' to 'data': ~3 Ohm

I think between the GND and DATA sensor wires resistance should be much higher - am I right? Below you can see a block diagram copied from the sensor datasheet (https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS18B20.pdf):
[image: ds18b20 block diagram]

Maybe black and white wires are +V and GND (which one is +V?), red is data? Or it's broken? Or something else?

I have bought it here - https://botland.com.pl/pl/czujniki-temperatury/10936-sonda-wodoodporna-z-czujnikiem-temperatury-ds18b20-5m-brazowy-silikon.html?search_query=sonda+temperatury&results=43 (language: polish). it is written:

- VCC - red
- GND - black or green
- data 1-wire - white or yellow

Comment: `between 5V and GND there is a 4k7 resistor` the diagram tells you to pullup the data line (DQ) to V_PU (5V), not between 5V and ground. That is just a power dissipator.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was a typo. 4k7 is between the data and +V.

Comment: Can you verify the meaning of the wire colors according to the package information of the datasheet? All the "DS18B20+" I see on e.g. digikey don't have color-coded wires on them. Do you have a link to where you bought them?

Comment: First post edited (added a link where I bought it)

Comment: Did you try to use the code in https://botland.com.pl/pl/content/134-arduino-w-polaczeniu-z-czujnikiem-temperatury-ds18b20? Did you, for the fun of it, remove the 4k7 resistor between DQ and VCC and see if that works?

Comment: It's a code copied from OneWire library example ('DS18x20_Temperature' example). I have tested it. I havn't removed pull-up resistor, it's a OneWire interface, I think it won't work without pull-upped data line. Is 'GND' to 'data': ~3 Ohm resistance normal? Look, between GND and DATA is a capacitor (DS18B20 block diagram).

Comment: If you measure 3 Ohms then there is a short between the wires. The sensor is bad.

Comment: When you test the sensor with nothing connected, is the resistance between the red and white wire the same in both directions? Does it change when the temperature changes? Perhaps there is an other temperature sensor inside. But it is probably a shortcut as @Rudy wrote.

Comment: Jot, no, it does not. I think thermistor would have higher resistance than 3 Ohm (~23oC).

Comment: Yes, thermistors have much higher resistance. Have you measured the resistance in the correct direction? A protection diode might produce a missleading measurement. Otherwise I'd say, your sensor is broke